# Node - Postgres driver setup with node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to integrate [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) driver and learn to do a simple CRUD operations. In my `app.js`, I do something like this:

```
...
var postgres = require('./adapters/postgres')
var postClient = new postgres(conf);
...
postClient.connect(function (dbconn) {
    app.dbconn = dbconn;
    app.conf = conf;

    console.log("************************************************************");
    console.log(new Date() + ' | CRUD Server Listening on ' + conf['web']['port']);
    console.log("************************************************************");

    server.listen(conf['web']['port']);

    var Routes = require('./routes/http-routes');
    new Routes(app);
});
```

Inside my `adapters/postgres.js` file, I have the following content:

```
const Client = require('pg');
const postClient = new Client(conf)({
    host: conf['postgres'].host,
    port: conf['postgres'].port,
    dbname: conf['postgres'].dbname,
    username: conf['postgres'].username,
    password: conf['postgres'].password,
    dbconn: null,
});
module.exports = postClient;
postClient.prototype.connect = function (cbk) {
    var self = this;
    client.connect(function (err, db) {
        console.log(new Date() + " | Postgres Server Connection Establised...");
        console.log(new Date() + " | Current database: ", db.databaseName);
        if (!err) {
            console.log(new Date() + " | Postgres Server Authenticated...");
            self.dbconn = db;
            cbk(db);
        } else {
            console.log(new Date() + " | Postgres Server Error in connection...");
            console.log(err);
            self.dbconn = db;
            cbk(db);
        }
    });
};
```

With the above code, I keep getting this error: `ReferenceError: conf is not defined` so I added it as `var conf = require('../config/conf');`. This is not a proper solution since I would like to pass it from the `app.js`. Next, even with this added I get the following error: `TypeError: Client is not a constructor`. Can someone guide on fixing both these errors?

Comment: @brianc any help will be appreciated!

Comment: A good example: [Designing a RESTful API With Node and Postgres](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/).

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks, I will use that as a base! Just for understanding can you help me with the current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export a factory function that takes the configuration object and returns an instance of the client. `Client` isn't a default export in `pg` so it needs to be destructured.

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const createPgClient = (conf) => {
    const pgClient = new Client(conf)({
        host: conf['postgres'].host,
        port: conf['postgres'].port,
        dbname: conf['postgres'].dbname,
        username: conf['postgres'].username,
        password: conf['postgres'].password,
        dbconn: null,
    });

    pgClient.prototype.connect = function (callback) {

        client.connect()
        .then(() => {
            console.log(new Date() + " | Postgres Server Authenticated...");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(new Date() + " | Postgres Server Error in connection...");
            console.log(err);
        })
        .finally(()=> {
            self.dbconn = this;
            callback(this);
        });

    };
    return pgClient;
};
module.exports = createPgClient;
```

Use this factory function in your `app.js` to create a client.

```
const createPgClient = require('./adapters/postgres')
cont pgClient = createPgClient(conf);

pg.connect(function (dbconn) {
    app.dbconn = dbconn;
    app.conf = conf;

    console.log("************************************************************");
    console.log(new Date() + ' | CRUD Server Listening on ' + conf['web']['port']);
    console.log("************************************************************");

    server.listen(conf['web']['port']);

    const Routes = require('./routes/http-routes');
    new Routes(app);
});
```

Comment: With the code posted above, I get the following error: 
`var pgClient = createPgClient(conf);
               ^
ReferenceError: createPgClient is not defined`